# Heater only blowing cold air

Tags: ford, hvac, heater, f-150

I have a 1997 F150 with a 4.2L engine. The engine warms to a normal operating temp. Blower motor is fine. No matter where the AC/Heater control switch is turned to I only get cold air. Im thinking the switch is bad. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/8569/1743 .. It could be anything from a broken blend door to a lack of coolant, although that could also present as overheating.

Comment: I would lean toward the valve for the heater core under the hood or the heater core itself.  Look for 2 hoses going to the firewall.  If one is hot, it is being blocked somewhere.  At this point, you need to drain the coolant, inspect the valve, and flush the heater core.  If both are hot, then it is an issue with the HVAC plumbing/doors.